# Неправильно работает drag & drop в vanile js

Tags: javascript, drag-n-drop

Некорректно работает drag & drop, помогите найти ошибку или переписать уже существующий код. Хотел реализовать это: внутри контейнера генирируются фигуры с рандомной высотой, шириной и цветом; их можно перемещать.

```js
let start = document.querySelector(".main__btn"),
    game = document.querySelector(".container");

start.addEventListener("click",startGame);

function startGame(){
    renderBox();
}
function renderBox(){
    game.innerHTML = ""; // удаляем дивы 
    let box = document.createElement("div");
    let boxSize = getRandom(30,500);
    let gameSize = game.getBoundingClientRect();
    let maxTop = gameSize.height - boxSize;
    let maxLeft = gameSize.width - boxSize;

    //drag&drop
    let startCursorX,
        startCursorY, 
        startX,
        startY;
    box.addEventListener("dragstart",function(e) {
        startCursorX = e.pageX;//Начальная позиция курсора по оси X
        startCursorY = e.pageY;//Начальная позиция курсора по оси Y
        startX = box.style.marginLeft.replace("px","")*1;// Нам нужны только цыфры без PX
        startY = box.style.marginTop.replace("px","")*1;
    });
    document.addEventListener("drag",function(e){
        box.style.marginLeft = ((e.pageX - startCursorX)) + "px";
        box.style.marginTop = ((e.pageY - startCursorY)) + "px";
    });
    box.addEventListener("dragend",function(e) {
        box.style.position = "absolute";
        box.style.marginLeft = startX + e.pageX- startCursorX + "px";//позиция элемента + позиция курсора - позиция курсоа в начале перетаскивания
        box.style.marginTop = startY + e.pageY- startCursorY+ "px";
    });

    





    box.style.height = boxSize + "px";
    box.style.width = boxSize + "px";
    box.style.top = getRandom(0,maxTop) + "px";
    box.style.left = getRandom(0,maxLeft) + "px";
    box.style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
    box.style.cursor = "pointer";
    box.draggable = true; 
    game.style.position = "relative";

    game.insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin",box);

}
function getRandomColor(){
    return "#" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
}
function getRandom(min,max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}
function getCoords(elem) {
    let box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();

    return {
        top: box.top + pageYOffset,
        left: box.left + pageXOffset
    }
}
```

```css
.container{
    margin: auto;
    width: 700px;
    height: 700px;
    border: solid 2px red;
    border-radius: 15px;
    position: relative;
}
.main__btn{
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    border: solid 1px black;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">

        

        
    </div>
    <button class="main__btn">запуск</button>
```

Comment: А что именно некорректно работает?

Comment: запустите код , так трудно объяснить ,ошибка в собыитии drag как я предпологаю

Comment: Я код запустил, ошибок не вижу.

Comment: 1 дроп нормально работает дальше блок раздваивается \

Comment: А зачем вы margin используете?

Comment: думаете лучше использовать left и top ? я просто новичок не совсем понимаю как лучше

Comment: Да, для задания положения элемента при `position: "absolute"` лучше использовать  `left` и `top`.

Comment: почему у меня элемент раздваивается ?

Comment: Он не раздваивается - один квадрат - тот который вы передвигаете с помощью margin, второй - делает сам браузер.

Comment: как мне это исправить ?

Comment: Сделайте перемещение с помощью left и top - проблема сама уйдет.